# statistical test to compare incomes in the first and second halves of a year

Tags: statistics, hypothesis-testing

Which statistical test should I use if I have this kind of problem:

I have an income statement for a year, so I decide to divide it into 1st half and 2nd half. then I find the mean for both. What test would be appropriate to determine whether the difference between 1st half and 2nd half is real or due to the number of jobs that the company got in each time perios?

Comment: have a look at this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_variance

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use a Welch (separate-variances) 2-sample t test.
See the formulas in the [*Wikipedia article*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Welch%27s_t-test#Calculations).

Because of possible seasonal factors, I think it would be dangerous to
use a test that assumes the population variances to be the same in the
two halves of the year.
The Welch test works well if the incomes for jobs are nearly normally distributed (if not, you should consider using a Mann-Whitney-Wilcoxon
signed rank test, not illustrated here.)

Roughly in the notation of the Wikipedia article, you would average the $n_1$ jobs in the first half of the year to get the sample mean $\bar X_1$ and find their sample 
variance to get $S_1^2.$ Similarly, use the $n_2$ jobs in the second
half of the year to get $\bar X_2$ and $S_1^2.$ Then find the degrees
of freedom and the $T$-statistic.

---

Here is an example, with $n_1 =105$ jobs in the first half of the year and $n_2 = 93$ in the second (incomes in thousands of dollars).

```
x1
 [1]  0.59  3.55  5.17 -1.69  3.86  4.01  1.85  1.91  1.87  1.22  2.05  1.00  1.45  3.13  4.92
[16]  2.78  1.98  1.18  1.33  7.83  3.27  2.02  2.12  3.92  1.61  0.10  4.15  0.95  2.97  1.13
[31]  5.20  2.05  1.58  2.00 -0.26  0.66 -1.36  0.32  2.41  2.07  5.90  0.86  1.29  2.44  1.01
[46]  1.06  0.79  0.50  1.95  2.01 -0.61  1.84  0.78  0.97  2.68  4.13  6.30  1.45  6.21  0.68
[61]  4.31  8.10  2.93  1.66  2.98  6.55  0.72  5.74  5.66  3.67  3.01  2.09  2.27  4.30  7.14
[76]  2.69  0.22  1.55  3.52  2.37  2.64  2.66  0.26  2.65  4.70  4.40  4.10  2.19  2.62  0.61
[91]  2.89  3.51  6.41  5.00  2.01  3.71  0.73  4.76  4.95  7.24  3.83  2.05  3.13  2.00  1.35
x2
 [1]  3.92  1.26  3.92  4.39  3.37  3.01  1.88  0.73  5.62  3.56  5.58  0.39  3.92  5.18  3.43
[16]  3.02  1.55  8.65  5.38  8.06  3.70  1.92 -0.28  1.91  4.07  6.03  4.13  0.57  5.17 -0.63
[31]  2.59  2.71 -1.37  5.80  1.94  2.66  6.99  5.09  3.23  4.78  4.50  7.66  4.19  4.77  4.37
[46]  2.56  3.74  7.60  1.31  3.80  6.91  2.91  0.87  1.33  2.52  1.38  2.85  2.46  3.04  4.52
[61]  5.06  7.70  3.33  2.70  7.18  7.76  3.61  2.67 -1.06  7.03  1.41  0.69 11.11  4.09  3.42
[76] -3.33  3.25  5.94  4.53  5.78  8.46  6.42  2.23  5.26  3.00  2.15 -3.64  1.53  4.72  8.92
[91]  4.75  5.05  1.09
```

Numbers in brackets show the job number of the first income on each line.
Notice that some jobs resulted in (mainly small) losses, due to unexpected costs for materials. Some summary
statistics are as follows:

```
summary(x1); sd(x1)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
-1.690   1.290   2.190   2.676   3.860   8.100 
## 1.970064
summary(x2); sd(x2)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
-3.640   2.150   3.610   3.698   5.170  11.110 
## 2.59855
```

Notice that the average income per job \$2,676 for the first half of the year is
smaller than the average \$3,698 for the second half of the year. The question
is whether these two sample means differ by enough to be statistically
significant.

Below is a 'notched' boxplot. The heavy bars at \$2,190 and \$3,698 represent
the medians. That the notches do not overlap is a rough indication that
population medians for the two parts of the year are different. (As is
typical of normal samples of these sizes, the boxplots indicate some
mild outliers, which can be ignored, unless a review of invoices reveals
a computational error.)

[image]

Results of the Welch test in R statistical software are as follows:

```
t.test(x1, x2)

       Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  x1 and x2
t = -3.0868, df = 170.44, p-value = 0.002362
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -1.6752067 -0.3683754
sample estimates:
mean of x mean of y 
2.676381  3.698172
```

The P-value 0.0024 < 0.05 indicates statistical significance at the 5% level.
The average income per job tended to be larger in the second
half of the year.

Your Question asked for a test that takes the number of jobs into
account. Notice that total income for the first half of the year was
about \$281,000 and for the second half slightly less about \$244,000. However, on
a *per job* basis, income was greater in the second half of the year.
Knowing in which half of the year the company did 'better' would require
a more comprehensive analysis of expenses, including advertising, payroll, and
so on.

*Note:* These are fake data. If you are using software that allows you
to compute the quantities necessary for the t test from the summary
statistic, you can use that software to verify the results for yourself. If $|T| > 1.974$
then reject the null hypothesis that the two halves of the year
produce equal average incomes per job at the 5% level of significance.

If you are using R statistical software, which requires the original data,
then you can generate the data in R just as I did:

```
set.seed(1234)
x1 = round(rnorm(105, 3, 2),2);  x2 = round(rnorm(93, 3.5, 2.5),2)
```

Notice that I used $\mu_1 =3.0$ and $\mu_2 = 3.5$ so it is not
astonishing that $H_0: \mu_1 = \mu_2$ is rejected in favor of the
alternative $H_a: \mu_1 \ne \mu_2.$